# In created:, my method doesn't work perfectly

Tags: css, node.js, vue.js, d3.js

I'm trying to make a simple vue.js & d3.js code. In the code, I want to plot some charts. For that, I'm trying to make some spaces for charts, by defining a `method('add_svg')` and run the method in created.

But, the `method('add_svg')` doesn't work what i intended. I had checked that the method was working, by inserting `console.log('Running')` for the first part of the method.

I could saw the message, 'Running', but the svg_space, i wanted to insert, wasn't inserted.

But when I UPDATE charts with same method in computed: part, it works.
In the computed: part, it generates some spaces several times, which means that it's working and the method has no problem.

Why is that?

Below is my code:

```
// GIVES CONSOLE.LOG MESSAGE('RUNNING') BUT DOES NOT APPEND SVG
created () {
  console.log("")
  this.add_svg() // append svg for chart
  this.plot([0, 0]) // basic plot with value = [0, 0]
},

...

// SAME METHOD, BUT IN HERE, IT GIVES ME WHAT I WANTED.
// BUT TO INITIALIZE, I WANT TO RUN THE METHOD IN created: part, not in computed
computed () {
  this.add_svg()
  this.plot( datum )
}

...

methods: {
  add_svg: function () {
    console.log("Adding some space for chart")
    d3.select('.chart_test2')
    .append('svg')
      .attr('class', 'svg_chart_test2')
      .attr('width', '10px')
      .attr('height', '10px')
  },
  other methods...
}
```

Comment: You are reaching to the DOM, when it is not yet created. Try your stuff in `mounted` hook, instead of `created`

Answer (score 0):

In Vue, you have to draw d3 charts on the mounted hook, rather than the created hook. You can't draw the chart if the page is not rendered - which is what happens when you use the created hook.

```
mounted () {
  this.add_svg() // append svg for chart
  this.plot([0, 0]) // basic plot with value = [0, 0]
}
```